# Get current Row number inside ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google Docs Spreadsheet, I would expect this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW())`

to fill the column like:

```
[   1]
[   2]
[   3]
[   4]
  ...
```

but instead it stops at 1.  What is happening here?  Is there another way to get the current row number in an arrayformula?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to specify a cell-range argument for ROW() in order to have more than one value.

Try it this way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A10))
```

This will fill a column with row numbers from 1 to 10.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now! I wanted it to fill the sheet and expand when rows are added, so I used: `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A2:A))` (starting under the header row)

Comment: If I need to be certain the numbers returned match the actual sheet row numbers they are on, but don't know which row the formula is starting on, is there a simpler method than this? `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",ROW(),":A"))))`

Answer (score 19):

The following may be a little simpler:

```
=arrayformula(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")))
```

or

```
=index(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when you want row number limited to not-empty row

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(filter(ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A";ROW();":A")));A2:A<>""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the 1st Column header

```
=arrayformula({"NO.";IFERROR(IF(B2:B<>"",ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")),""))})
```

If you have an error saying:

> "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation,
> see File > Settings."

Go to File > Settings > Calculation Tab > Iterative calculation

Comment: I have an error with this formula: "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Settings."

Comment: Go to File > Settings > Calculation Tab > Iterative calculation